# Programación asp.net para invidentes (ciegos, sordos etc.)

Tags: asp.net

Quisiera hacer mis páginas asp.net accesibles para invidentes. ¿De qué herramientas dispongo1? ¿Hay algo especial que hacer con los controles?

Comment: Bienvenido seas a la comunidad, te comento que deberías leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], la pregunta aunque interesante es basada en opiniones y no tiene en realidad un problema puntual a resolver dado lo anterior es seguro termine cerrada.

Comment: Un sordo no deberia tener un impedimento importante para hacer uso de una pagina web. Una persona con problemas de vision si, y para eso los navegadores y sistemas operativos tienen sistemas de ayuda que pueden ser mejorados con el uso de algunos tags html. deberias buscar sobre eso.